# I have encrypted iPhone backup in Windows and its Encryption Password. How to open SQLite DB files from the backup manually without using iTunes

Tags: iphone, sqlite, encryption, passwords, backup

I have encrypted iPhone backup in Windows and its Encryption Password. How to open an SQLite DB files from the backup manually without using iTunes. Without encryption I am able open it using any SQL Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this python script [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/source/browse/python_scripts/backup_tool.py).

```
python backup_tool.py
```

Comment: Can I call this from within VB.NET? or any other .NET program? Thank you.